# LWJGL - Text's color changes background's color

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a serious problem with my LWJGL program. 
If I set one of my text's colour, the background's color changes, too. 

I think I know why, I just put all of the drawing things in an infinite loop, and maybe that's the reason.
Can you help me with this? Am I correct with the reason of the problem? If yes, how can I solve that? If not, what do you think, what is the problem? 
Here's my code: 

The main class:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public class DoomMain {
public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int SCALE = 1;

private static State state;

public DoomMain() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        Display.setTitle("Tomco - Doom");
        Display.create();
    } catch(LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {                            
        state = State.MENU;     

        switch(state) {
            case INTRO:
                new Intro();
                break;
            case MENU:
                new MainMenu();
                break;
            case CREDITS:
                break;
            case GAME:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DoomMain(); 
}
}
```

The MainMenu class:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public class MainMenu {

private Texture background;
private TrueTypeFont doomfont;

private boolean ana = false;

public MainMenu()  {                
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glViewport(0,0,DoomMain.WIDTH,DoomMain.HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,DoomMain.WIDTH,DoomMain.HEIGHT,0,1,-1);
    glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);    
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    drawBackground();
    drawText();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

private void drawBackground() {
    try {
        background = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",new FileInputStream(new File("res/textures/mainmenu/doom_00340461.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(background.getTextureWidth(),0); 
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(background.getTextureWidth(),background.getTextureHeight());
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(0,background.getTextureHeight());
    }
    glEnd();
}

private void drawText() {
    Color.white.bind();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/fonts/DooM.ttf");
        Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,inputStream);
        awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(24f);
        doomfont = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont,ana);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doomfont.drawString(200,100,"Start new game",Color.red);
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried clearing the color after drawing the string? i think i vaguely remember something like this...

Comment: Aside: are you loading the background from a file every time through the loop? That's bound to be very slow. Don't do that. Load it once and cache it.

Comment: Simiil: With glClear or glClearColor? I tried glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) after drawing the string. Still buggy. Thomas: Thanks for the advice. How I can cache it? Please help, I'm beginner in OpenGL.

Comment: You have a much bigger problem here though. You create a new `MainMenu` object every frame. In addition your load your texture and font every single frame. Make the object once and load the resources once, then start rendering stuff. The way you do it now is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Why do you need to call `Color.white.bind()` when you already pass a color to `drawString(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all : The `Color.white.bind()` call in your `drawText()` function is probably what is affecting the background.

Here is a **quick and dirty** example of how to only load the data once. I've moved data loading to the `loadData()` function. The `DoomMain` class is created once after the screen is opened, loadData() is called before the main loop and you call your drawing using `menu.draw()`.

Ideally you would load all the resources you need in one place first, then pass the objects to `DoomMain` at initialization. You might want to use that texture and font in other places as well.. and you don't want to load it multiple times.

```
public DoomMain()
{
    // Open screen here since we need a context to make textures etc
    ...
    // Make objects for your different parts
    MainMenu menu = MainMenu();
    menu.loadData(); // <- Loads the texture and font

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {                           
        state = State.MENU;     
        switch(state) {
            ...
            case MENU:
                menu.draw();
                break;
            ...
        }
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
}
```

MainMenu

```
public class MainMenu
{       
    private Texture background;
    private TrueTypeFont doomfont;
    private boolean ana = false;

    public MainMenu() { }

    public void loadData()
    {
        // Load the background texture
        try {
            background = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",new FileInputStream(new File("res/textures/mainmenu/doom_00340461.png")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
        }
        // Load and initialize the font here
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/fonts/DooM.ttf");
            Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,inputStream);
            awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(24f);
            doomfont = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont,ana);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glViewport(0,0,DoomMain.WIDTH,DoomMain.HEIGHT);
        glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0,DoomMain.WIDTH,DoomMain.HEIGHT,0,1,-1);
        glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);    
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

        drawBackground();
        drawText();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
    }

    private void drawBackground() 
    {
        ... bind background texture
        ... draw your quad  
    }

    private void drawText() 
    {       
        doomfont.drawString(....);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code like that, but now, I've got a NullPointerException in the main class. Any ideas why? EDIT: Oh, maybe I know why. Maybe because the images and the fonts are declared in an other function. I mean, I give the "real" pictures and fonts to the variables in the loadData(), and I use them on the drawBackground() and drawText() parts.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the NullPointerException, I just forgot to call the menu.loadData(); But there's a new, interesting bug. Instead of a picture in the background, there are some letters and signs, like that: http://oi39.tinypic.com/2ugyx6o.jpg

Comment: Do you bind your texture before you draw the quad?

Comment: Oh, that was the problem. Thanks. But the main bug is still there. The background's color changes with the text's color :S

Comment: Did you remove the `Color.white.bind()`?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the texture will be multiplied by the current color. As a state machine, the "current color" is whenever you set it last. In your case, when you draw text; when you enter the loop again, that same color is used for the texture.

To simplify the problem, you can reduce the whole drawText routine to just setting the color:

```
LOOP:
    a) draw background
    b) set color
```

results in: ... set color; draw background ...

The glClear function clears the buffers of what is already drawn, but not the color to be used next.

As a solution, you can explicitly change the color just before you draw the texture. glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) will produce the texture as is, and any other value will work as a color filter (just as it is now).

Another solution is to change the texture drawing behavior with [glTexEnv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml). Assuming the texture is GL_RGBA, then calling glTexEnv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE) works. The linked page contains a table with different settings and their effects.

Comment: Thank you for your help with it, but with the help of Grimmy, I solved the problem!

Comment: Giving this one points because it addresses the root cause of the issue. I got greedy and solved a couple of other problems as well.